# determine if array contains specific integer in octave

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have an array which looks like

> test = {1,2,3};

I want to determine if an integer belongs in the array. I tried using ismember() and any() but they both return this:

> binary operator '==' not implemented for 'cell' by 'scalar' operations

How will I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to check if an integer exists in a matrix:

```
test = [1, 2, 3];
any (test == 2)
ans =  1
```

But in your question you use a cell array. In this case I would first convert it to a matrix, then do the same:

```
b = {1,2,3};
any (cell2mat (b) == 2)
ans =  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about checking if an **array** has a given integer but you're using a **cell**. They're quite different.

If you want to stick to cells you can iterate over it like so

```
test = {1, 2, 3};
number = 2;
hasNumber = false;
for i = 1:size(test,2)
  if(test{i} == number)
    hasNumber = true;
    break;
  end
end
```

For arrays, on the other hand, you could do just this, for example

```
test = [1, 2, 3];
number = 2;
hasNumber = ~isempty(test(test == number));
```